# Problem with resolution of xfig figures and beamer slides

Tags: resolution, xfig

I am finishing my presentation for a university project. There are several figures I am using from the xfig package onto my Latex document (Overleaf). When I put the presentation on the big screen the resolution is horrible. Instead of  straight lines I get small circular dots close together..., because xfig has exported them as multiple `{\tiny .}`. Is there a way to overcome this?

Thank you so much for any help you can give me.

Comment: There may be differences in the renderers/previewers used. Did you download the output PDF and view it in Adobe Reader or a different PDF reader?

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Reader DC

Comment: Try changing your Overleaf preview settings (click on the Overleaf menu icon above the file list) to "Native" to see if it works better. If not, it would be best to contact support@overleaf.com with your project's URL, so that the support staff can have a closer look.

Comment: Thank you but that did not work.

Comment: Actually it looks like xfig has exported all your figures as tiny dots, hence the dotted look.

Comment: What is the output format of xfig you used? I would recommend latex + pict2e macros, if pattern fills are not needed, or latex + tikz.

Comment: When I try these I get several errors... Do I need any special packages in my Latex document? Note that when I export using eps extension it works! However, I can not incorporate any latex code (i.e. $$) when I use the eps. extension...

Comment: latex + pict2e: \usepackage{pict2e}, latex + tikz: \usepackage{tikz} and optionally, depending on the contents of the figure, \usetikzlibrary{pattern,arrows.meta,bending}